# android release error Avoid non_default construtor in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I release my project i have this error:

> Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)` instead `[ValidFragment]`

Please help me this is my code

```
public class Main2 extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

   mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }


        });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setIcon(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getDrawableId(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
          mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
```

and

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Z_Hello(mcontext);
                case 1:
                    return new X_Board(mcontext);
                case 2:
                    return new X_Board_2(mcontext);
                case 3:
                    return new X_Board3(mcontext);
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

and fragment

```
public class X_Board extends Fragment{

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstance) {
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.board_list, container, false);

return view

}
```

so i try it

```
   (fragment)
  public static X_Board newInstance(int h){

    X_Board ff = new X_Board(context);
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("num",h);
     ff.setArguments(args);

    return ff;
 }

    (activity)
    Fragment fragment = X_Board.newInstance(1);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    (fragment oncreate)
   mNum = getArguments() !=null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
```

but still error show..

help me please i find All Questuions but don't solve it help me..

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not a proper way of calling the fragment. Instead you should use :

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, new YourGotoFragment());
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response where i insert that code? and R.id.container is what? you mean android.R.id.content?

Comment: it should be the id of the parent view, in your case it seems to be `R.id.pager`

Comment: container is the id of your fragment container in your activity's xml file.